# Is fasting continuously for months permissible?

Tags: sawm

Is it permissible to fast continuously for months. Prophet saw asked young men to fast if they are single. So is it encouraged? I feel very peaceful and relaxing while fasting continuously. But I heard that it's not good to health. My family and friends discourage me and ask me to do alternatively. Please give advice.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say: I admire your will.

This is the Hadith you need to read.

> Sahih Al-Bukhari - صحيح البخاري
>
> 30. Fasting - كتاب الصوم 55) Chapter: The right of the body in observing As-Saum. Narrated `Abdullah bin`Amr bin Al-`As:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said to me, "O Abdullah! Have I not been
>   informed that you fast during the day and offer prayers all the
>   night." Abdullah replied, "Yes, O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)!" The Prophet
>   (ﷺ) said, "Don't do that; fast for few days and then give it up for
>   few days, offer prayers and also sleep at night, as your body has a
>   right on you, and your wife has a right on you, and your guest has a
>   right on you. And it is sufficient for you to fast three days in a
>   month, as the reward of a good deed is multiplied ten times, so it
>   will be like fasting throughout the year." I insisted (on fasting) and
>   so I was given a hard instruction. I said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! I
>   have power." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Fast like the fasting of the
>   Prophet (ﷺ) David and do not fast more than that." I said, "How was
>   the fasting of the Prophet (ﷺ) of Allah, David?" He said, "Half of the
>   year," (i.e. he used to fast on every alternate day). Afterwards when
>   `Abdullah became old, he used to say, "It would have been better for
>   me if I had accepted the permission of the Prophet (ﷺ) (which he gave
>   me i.e. to fast only three days a month).
>
> Reference: 1975 English reference: Vol. 3, Book 31, Hadith 196
>   In-book reference: Book 30, Hadith 82 Grade: Sahih

and this is where you can find it : http://www.gowister.com/hadith/bukhari/1935/

Comment: But is it okay if I fast one day alternative ? Here it's more about the peace of my mind and being in a state of more obedience to Allah.

Comment: That would be the maximum according to the hadith. So yes it is okay to fast one day alternative (one day on then the next day off).

Comment: @Fashithmusliyarakam and just one thing. Reading the quran every day will also help you to reach the state of mind peace.